# bash script issue launching programs

Tags: java, linux, bash, amazon-web-services, makefile

I have a bash script that is executed when an AWS EC2 ubuntu instance boots, via the AWS server launch configuration (which is essentially also bash script) using the following command

```
sudo -u ubuntu /vagrant/test/startAll.sh
```

The issue I'm seeing is the java programs don't run if they're the last entry in the bash script, but run fine if not the last entry. I'm a bit stumped as to why it's happening.

Here's the bash script...

**startAll.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# set -x

brokerSrvDIR="/vagrant/test/ppp"
meetingSrvDIR="/vagrant/test/clone"
notifySrvDIR="/vagrant/test/notification/production/notificationsrv"
workerDIR="/vagrant/test/ppp/production/ppworker2"

#( cd $workerDIR &&  { make runworker >>log/out.txt 2>&1 & } )

( cd $brokerSrvDIR && { ./ppp_broker >>log/out.txt 2>&1 & } )

( cd $notifySrvDIR && { make runnotify >>log/out.txt 2>&1 & } )

( cd $meetingSrvDIR && { ./meetingsrv > /dev/null 2>>log/out.txt & } )

( cd $workerDIR &&  { make runworker >>log/out.txt 2>&1 & } )

#( sleep 10s && cd $brokerSrvDIR && { ./ppp_broker >>log/out.txt 2>&1 & } )
```

`ppp_broker` and `meetingsrv` are C executables
`make runworker` and `make runnotify` are Make calls that run java programs

Here's the Makefile for the worker java program

**Makefile**

```
DLIBS=-lzmq -lczmq
LDFLAGS=
CFLAGS=-DDEBUG
CPFLAG=-cp /usr/local/share/java/*:.
CPFLAGDB=-cp /usr/local/share/java/*:. -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:ErrorFile=log/hs_err_pid_%p.log
CPFLAGP=-cp /usr/local/share/java/*:. -

JFLAGS = -g
JAVAC=javac
sources = $(wildcard *.java)
classes = $(sources:.java=.class)

all: $(classes)

clean :
        rm -f *.class

%.class : %.java
        #export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH):/usr/local/lib/*  
        #export CLASSPATH=$(CLASSPATH):/usr/local/share/java/*:. 
        $(JAVAC) $(JFLAGS) $(CPFLAG) $<

.ONESHELL:
runworker :
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH):/usr/local/lib/*
        export CLASSPATH=$(CLASSPATH):/usr/local/share/java/*:.
        java $(CPFLAGDB) -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib/ ppworker2
```

**Update: set x output**

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxx:/vagrant/test$ /vagrant/test/startAll.sh 
+ brokerSrvDIR=/vagrant/test/ppp
+ meetingSrvDIR=/vagrant/test/clone
+ notifySrvDIR=/vagrant/test/notification/production/notificationsrv
+ workerDIR=/vagrant/test/ppp/production/ppworker2
+ cd /vagrant/test/ppp
+ cd /vagrant/test/notification/production/notificationsrv
+ ./ppp_broker
+ cd /vagrant/test/clone
+ make runnotify
+ cd /vagrant/test/ppp/production/ppworker2
+ ./meetingsrv
ubuntu@ip-xxxx:/vagrant/test$ + make runworker
```

Output from `ps` after running the above:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxx:/vagrant/test$ ps -ef | grep make
ubuntu    2104     1  0 18:06 pts/0    00:00:00 make runnotify
ubuntu    2144  1479  0 18:06 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto make
```

So the bash script executes the make call according to set x, but it's not actually running.

Comment: Problem aside that makefile isn't working like you think. Specifically those `export` lines are **not** affecting the environment of the `java` line that follows them. Each line in a make recipe is run in its own shell session (unless you use the `.ONESHELL` option in make).

Comment: When you say it doesn't run as the last entry what do you mean exactly? what happens? What does `set -x` show you is happening? Does *any* content after the `make` call make it work? Or only some other backgrounded process line?

Comment: @EtanReisner -- I've updated the Question to show the set x output and ps.  Thanks for the makefile info, I'll add .ONESHELL and see if it makes a difference

Comment: @EtanReisner -- `( cd $workerDIR &&  { make runworker >>log/out.txt 2>&1 & } )`  is the last command in the bash file. It is executed by bash according to `set x`, but no `make runworker` process is running. However if I move that line in the bash file above one of the C program commands the `make runwoker` process will run. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong in the bash script or makefile, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Oh and I tried the `.ONESHELL:` command but the problem still exists. I'll update the question to show the additional command in the Makefile

Comment: `.ONESHELL` wasn't going to help with your problem but was going to fix the operation of `make runworker` to actually do what you expect. As would putting those commands all on a single line (or backslash extended) in the makefile.

Comment: 1. Don't you think you should grep for `java`, not for `make`?
2. What gets logged in `log/out.txt`?

Comment: If the java application doesn't fork/detach then make shouldn't exit until the java app does. But checking for the java process is a better idea then checking for make regardless. As is checking the log file.

Comment: Hmm I spun up a new EC2 instance and now everything works... weird.  Thanks for eveyone's help, and hopefully the issue won't appear again :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I spun up a new EC2 instance and everything now works. I'll put it down to EC2 weirdness for now, but if it happens again I'll dig deeper. Thanks!